# OpenEdge Select using today in SSIS

Tags: select, ssis, openedge

I have this select working in an SSIS package.

```
select order, date_req, date_creat,cust_num, bl_num
from pub.orders
where date_req > '02/20/2017'
and     bl_num   > 0
order by cust_num, date_req
```

I have an ODBC connection to a Progress OpenEdge Database.
I want to change the date literal to a date function for **today**

I need help coding this.

Comment: Curdate()? I'm guessing here so I'll leave it as a comment for you to try out and not as an answer! https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dmsrf/curdate.html#

Comment: select order, date_req, date_creat,cust_num, bl_num
from pub.orders
where date_req = CURDATE()
and     bl_num   > 0
order by cust_num, date_req

Comment: This worked great.   Thank You.

Comment: Since it's now a legitimate answer (you checked it for me). I posted it as an answer as well, feel free to upvote and accept! That's how you say thank you on SO.

Answer (score 2):

Use the curdate() function.

See documentation here:
https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html%23page/dmsrf/curdate.html%23